# How to use INDEX, MATCH and SMALL functions to populate multiple values with singular lookup value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a system that populates results from another sheet. As shown in the images below there are different "buckets". The buckets are various date ranges and there are different tasks in the separate buckets. Ultimately, I want to pull over the tasks that correlate with the appropriate bucket.

Initially, I tried doing this via a `VLOOKUP`. However, I quickly found that if you are using the same lookup value, `VLOOKUP` is not ideal for this. I searched and found that using `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `SMALL` functions was best for this. (I do not have Office 365--using Excel 2016).

I followed a guide that lead me to write a formula like this:

`=INDEX(Planner!C11:C168,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!A11:A334),MATCH(ROW(Planner!A11:A312),ROW(Planner!C11:C377)),""),ROWS($A$1:A1)))`

I used this instruction: https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/

What is happening is that I am getting a #REF error. I have quadrupale checked the formula. I'm not sure why a reference error is populating.

Does anyone see something wrong in my formula or recommend a different way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. The formula was actually perfect. I had a reference error on the sheet that I was referencing that was throwing it off.

So, to someone like myself that didn't know reference errors in the data you are referencing will throw off your formula!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.